# Bootstrap3.js and Wordpress jQuery v1.10.2 do not work properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with Bootstrap.js 3. More precisely, my problem is with collapse.js for menu scrolling function and jquery library from Wordpress 1.3.7.

I would like to use jquery from WP. When I enqueue bootstrap js, scrolling simply doesn't work. If I delete Wordpress jquery.js from wp-includes/js/jquery and add an older version of JQuery (i.e: v1.9.1) the scrolling function works great!

Is that possible that boostrap.js has some conflict with new jquery.js?

This is my code in functions.php

```
function my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');   
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/bootstrap.js',   array('jquery'), true );
}

 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: Wordpress uses jQuery's no conflict mode, which is probably the issue.  I doubt that Bootstrap's scripts are using $ directly, but your initialization of them probably is.

Comment: No errors. Strange is that everything works well with older jquery when I add it inside wp-includes. What is your suggestion? Should I change something in functions.php code?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of jQuery's no conflict mode. You need to have following statement in between jQuery script inclusion and bootstrap script inclusion

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

or go to wp-includes/js/jquery and delete or comment last statement which is like

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```